# Avoid indexes for DML in a particular procedure (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one procedure with multiple update statements(DMLs).

So is there any way to  avoid index for that particular table to improve the performance of update statements.

Comment: Procedures don't have indexes... your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use [`ignore index`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html) in your DML inside the procedure.

Otherwise, you cannot particularly do this for a procedure.

Further `Syntax` details on `Update` usage from [Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)